# Pandas Dataframe of boolean to classification Serie

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean, classification

I have a Pandas DataFrame like that:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | False | False | False | False | False | True |
| 1 | False | True | False | False | False | False |
| 2 | False | True | False | False | False | False |
| 3 | False | True | False | False | False | False |
| 4 | True | False | False | False | False | False |

And I want to transform it into a Serie like:

|  | Classes |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | F |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | B |
| 4 | A |

Is someone knows the way to do that ? :D

Comment: TL;DR - `new_df = df.idxmax(axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

You could try with `.dot`:

```
output = df.dot(df.columns).rename("Classes")

>>> output
0    F
1    B
2    B
3    B
4    A
Name: Classes, dtype: object
```